# Recent Gnosis goerli behavior change

Tags: gnosis-safe, typescript, goerli

Code that works on ethereum mainnet/rinkeby and up until recently worked on goerli doesn't work on goerli anymore.

The code in question is proposing a Gnosis-Safe transaction using

```
@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk: ^2.1.0,
@gnosis.pm/safe-ethers-lib: ^1.1.0,
@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client: ^1.1.2,
```

Up until these 3 steps including, everything looks dandy

```
const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(safeTransactionData);
await safeSdk.signTransaction(safeTransaction);
const safeTxHash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
```

and we have a valid looking Gnosis Safe transaction hash (`safeTxHash`)

I would have expected, as per the code, that the next step will fail on any issues.

```
await serviceSdk.proposeTransaction(transactionConfig);
```

Comments in code `SafeServiceClient`

```
    /**
     * Creates a new multi-signature transaction with its confirmations and stores it in the Safe Transaction Service.
     *
     * @param proposeTransactionConfig - The configuration of the proposed transaction
     * @returns The hash of the Safe transaction proposed
     * @throws "Invalid Safe address"
     * @throws "Invalid safeTxHash"
     * @throws "Invalid data"
     * @throws "Invalid ethereum address/User is not an owner/Invalid signature/Nonce already executed/Sender is not an owner"
     */
    proposeTransaction({ safeAddress, senderAddress, safeTransaction, safeTxHash, origin }: ProposeTransactionProps): Promise<void>;
```

But it executes without fail.
However, The transaction cannot be found in the website's queue, nor can it be retrieved via `safeClient.getTransaction`. it was never created as far as I can see.

Is that a gnosis/goerli regression? obsolete libraries? other?
Up until a couple of days ago(12/10/22) same code functioned as expected.

(edit)
The misbehavior is reproducible by wonderland's [gnosis-safe-proposer](https://github.com/defi-wonderland/gnosis-safe-proposor)

Comment: could you please share the safe address and the transaction hash?

Comment: @mikheevm safe is```0x37918D4DAD5dE0af86753eDFCd83CBDD04c49712``` I created a second one just to make sure it's not the safe ```0x7C114e9013124DE655f4922C0213bFfc96AEf42c``` but got the same behavior .

The last transaction hash for the first safe is ```0x3a5d652bf0fe1a30a433afeca0de8c901f93aa3a0d88ecc689c28a37df2612b8```

The last transaction hash for the 2nd safe is 
```0xaaf7c54e08294d1dfd5b62182ecf6c2259801d4400a7acf74e2ab2f72cfee0fd```

Comment: The problem is very likely due to requests to ```https://safe-transaction.goerli.gnosis.io``` while the most updated goerli(?) runs on ```https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global/```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API URL `https://safe-transaction.goerli.gnosis.io` is not fully functional the correct URL to use is `https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global`

I found it using the [safe-client-gateway](https://safe-client.gnosis.io/index.html) API

```
$ curl https://safe-client.gnosis.io/v1/chains/5/about
{ 
 "transactionServiceBaseUri":"https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global/",
 "name":"safe-client-gateway",
 "version":"3.36.0",
 "buildNumber":"2953"
}
```

Once I realized the correct API URL I found the full [OpenAPI specifications](https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global/).

It will be helpful if someone can drop a comment with the official location where such information is formally distributed.

Answer (score 2):

We landed on the same solution (as OP)! The official information is here: https://forum.gnosis-safe.io/t/transaction-service-migration-october-2022/1550 which we found via the gnosis UI at https://gnosis-safe.io/